# How to silence/rectify this issue: face-explorer.el: Warning: Use keywords

Tags: warning

```
$ ecat app/models/insurance_policy_revenue.rb
../dotfiles/.emacs.d/my_lisp/face-explorer/face-explorer.el: Warning: Use keywords rather than deprecated positional arguments to `define-minor-mode'
../dotfiles/.emacs.d/my_lisp/face-explorer/face-explorer.el: Warning: Use keywords rather than deprecated positional arguments to `define-minor-mode'
...
```

I'm using [ecat](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to remove the need for those warnings then change the definitions that use `define-minor-mode` so that they use those keywords instead of providing the same info as (positional) arguments.
2. If you just want to prevent the warnings from being displayed/printed then you can fiddle with the available warning options described in node [Warning Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Options.html) of the Elisp manual.
3. Otherwise, just ignore those "warnings". There's nothing really to *warn* about.

(This has nothing to do with shell or shell command `ecat`. The warning message tells you that it's about some code in file `face-explorer.el`.)